# Deserialize JSON string in C# without using reflection

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm working on a sandbox solution in Sharepoint, the important restrictions (regarding to this question) due to that are the use of .net 3.5 and there are no reflections allowed.

---

***EXAMPLE 1***

If I try to deserialize as JSON string into a simple class like this it works fine:

**JSON STRING**

```
{"field":"Picture1","url":"whatever"}
```

**C# CLASS**

```
public class PictureSetting
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

---

***EXAMPLE 2***

But if I try to deserialize a bit more complex string I get an error:

**JSON STRING**

```
{
  "Rows": [
    {
      "Columns": [
        {
          "Width": "100"
        }
      ]
    }    
  ]
}
```

**C# CLASSES**

```
internal class PageStructure
{
    public List<StructureElement> Rows { get; set; }
    public PageStructure()
    {
        Rows = new List<StructureElement>();
    }
}

internal class StructureElement
{
    public List<BlockAssigment> Columns { get; set; }
    public StructureElement()
    {
        Columns = new List<BlockAssigment>();
    }
}

internal class BlockAssigment
{
    public string Width { get; set; }
}
```

**ERROR**

Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

---

***DESERIALIZATION**

The code I use for deserialization of both examples is just standard .net:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var obj = serializer.Deserialize<PageStructure>("jsonstring");
```

---

So it seems that for the first example .net is **not** using reflection because that works. So the question is:

**Is there a way to deserialize the second example without having .net using reflection internally?**

Modifying both JSON string and C# classes are no problem, I just have to keep the structure (base object with rows including columns) somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the biggest problem is actually here:

```
public class PictureSetting // public, works
```

versus

```
internal class PageStructure // non-public, permission denied
```

it sounds to me like the sandbox is preventing reflection *of non-public types/members*. This would be consistent with most sandboxes, for example Silverlight: you can use reflection, but only for things that the could would be able to do normally - i.e. access public types / members. Try making `PageStructure`, `StructureElement` and `BlockAssigment` into `public` classes.

Comment: Yes, thats it! Awesome, thank you very much! I changed it to public and it works. So it seems that the sandbox is NOT prohibiting the reflection generally but the non-public as you said. Interesting. I learn a bit every day :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use this service http://json2csharp.com/ to generate correct C# clasees for parsing json.